# How to avoid repeating drop-down options?

Tags: php, html

In my form made from PHP and HTML, in the drop-down list there are 4 options. If I select any option and submit it, it works fine, but after I do that, if I open the same drop-down again to update it then there is 5 options. That means there are 4 options and the previously selected option. How can I stop this happening?
thank you
code below

```
<select name ="curstatus"  required="">
    <option value="<?php echo $curstatus; ?>"><?php echo $curstatus; ?> </option>
    <option value="2">Received</option>
    <option value="3">Under Processing</option>
    <option value="4">Completed</option>
    <option value="5">Out Of Office</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are `Received`, `Under Processing, `Completed` and `Out Of Office` dynamic options? I mean are they coming from database?

Comment: yes, coming from DB enum values

Comment: So you would somehow loop to display them? Could you include that code?

Comment: i just put the above code  only in form

Comment: Just show the four options, and set `selected` for the one that matches `$curstatus`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name ="curstatus" required="">
    <option value="2" <?php if ($currstatus == 2) { ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Received</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if ($currstatus == 3) { ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Under Processing</option>
    
    <!-- and all other options in the same way -->
</select>
```

You can also make a PHP array with options and values and just loop over that.

Comment: thank for your help , i tried but the current value always the first option, i want the current value as default